# how to check an image is available in an array

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I want to check one particular image is available in an array or not

I tried this method. Not working properly. How to solve this?

```
UIImage *imgname=img.image;

for (UIImage *img1 in imgNameArray) {

    if([img1 isEqual:imgname])
    {
        NSLog(@"yes");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"No");
    }
}
```

`imgarray` is blob type image from database.

Comment: your naming is really weird: the object `img` isn't an UIImage, while `imgname` isn't a string, but a UIImage. and your iteration variable is called `img1`, while it iterate over all images, not just the first.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a look at the NSArray's documentation, you will find a method, that does exactly what you are doing: [`-containsObject:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BABCEJDI);